# how can I trigger update and read event from select method of kendo scheduler?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

Is it possible to invoke update and read event from save method?
this function is attached with kendo scheduler control.

```
<script>
   function saveChanges(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //I want to trigger update and then read method.
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The dataSource of the Kendo Scheduler has a `read()` method.

You can get to it through the options object, if you use one:
`$scope.schedulerOptions.dataSource.read()`

Another way is through the scheduler using jQuery:
`$("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler").dataSource.read()`

Comment: thank you very much for the reply.

the solution given by you is useful to read source from given url (using angularjs).

I'm looking for what to update changes while executing scheduler save function invoking